# Calculate total price based on multiple selected radio button- Angular 9/10

Tags: angular, typescript, radio-button, angular-components, ngmodel

I'm currently working on a shopping cart and created a form with multiple radio button group. The user must choose one package from the first group, then the other groups are optional. On the side panel I'd like to show the prices of the chosen products one by one (I could achieve this so far) and the total price dynamically.
At the moment I can only display the total price if all 4 radio buttons are selected, or if only the first one.
That is my first project in Angular, and I'm stuck with this part.

Here is my HTML code: (showing only 2 set of radio button groups, the rest is similar to these)

```
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-9">
            <form>

          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6" *ngFor="let item of plan.linespeed; let i = index;">
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="internet" class="card-input-element" id="net" [(ngModel)]="radioSelected" value="{{plan.linespeed[i].price}}" (change)="onItemChange()" />
                    <div class="card panel-default card-input">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-auto"><div class="card-title">{{plan.linespeed[i].name}}</div></div>
                       <div class="col-auto ml-auto">
                        <div class="card-title">{{plan.linespeed[i].price}}<span>&#44;</span><span>&#45;</span><span>&#47;</span>md</div>
                      </div>
                      </div>
                     
                      <div class="divider"></div>
                      <div class="card-subtitle">{{plan.linespeed[i].speed}}</div>
                      <ul>
                        <li>No set-up fee</li>
                        <li>No binding</li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                </label>
              </div>

            </div>
                  
  
                    <div *ngIf="radioSelected">
                      
                        <h1>Would You like to add IP-TV to your package?</h1>
                        <input type="radio" name="tv" value="yes" [(ngModel)]="tvchoice" ><label>Yes, I'd love to </label>
                        <input type="radio" name="tv" value="no" [(ngModel)]="tvchoice"><label>No, thanks, I'm fine</label>

                        <div *ngIf="tvchoice == 'yes'">

                        <h2>Select a TV-package: </h2>

                        <div class="row">

                          <div class="col-sm-6" *ngFor="let item of plan.tvpackage; let i = index;">
                      
                            <label>
                              <input type="radio" name="tvpackage" class="card-input-element" [(ngModel)]="tvSelected" value="{{plan.tvpackage[i].price}}" (change)="onTvChange()"/>
                    
                                <div class="card panel-default card-input">
                                  <div class="row">
      
                                    <div class="col-auto">
                                      <div class="card-title">{{plan.tvpackage[i].name}}</div>
                                    </div>
                                   <div class="col-auto ml-auto">
                                    <div class="card-title">{{plan.tvpackage[i].price}}<span>&#44;</span><span>&#45;</span><span>&#47;</span>md</div>
                                  </div>
                                  </div>
                                 
                                  <div class="divider"></div>
                                
                                  <ul>
                                    <li>No set-up fee</li>
                                    <li>No binding</li>
      
                                  </ul>
                                </div>
                    
                            </label>
                            
                          </div>

                        </div>

                      </div>                    
                    </div>
```

Here is the shopping cart:

```
    <h1>Shopping Cart</h1>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">

        <h4>Internet Plan:</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">

        <p>{{radioSelected}}</p>
      
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6">

        <h4>Tv Package:</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">

        <p>{{tvSelected}}</p>
      
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6">

        <h4>Optional TV:</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">

        <p>{{tvOptionSelected}}</p>
      
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6">

        <h4>IP-Telephony Plan:</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">

        <p>{{ipSelected}}</p>
      
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6">

        <h4>Total Price:</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">

        <p>{{calcTotalPrice()}}</p>
      
      </div>

      <button>Add to Cart</button>

    </div>
```

And here is the Typescript code:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatAccordion } from '@angular/material/expansion';
import { ActivatedRoute, ParamMap, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { PlanService } from 'src/app/services/plan.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-plan',
  templateUrl: './plan.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./plan.component.css']
})
export class PlanComponent implements OnInit {
  plan$ : any = [];
  radioSel:any;
  radioSelected:string;
  tvSelected:string; 
  tvSel: any;
  optionSel: any; 
  tvOptionSelected: string;
  ipSel: any;
  ipSelected: string;

  @ViewChild(MatAccordion) accordion: MatAccordion;
 
   constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
     private router: Router,
     private planService: PlanService) { 
     }
 
     getSelecteditem(){
      this.radioSel = this.plan$.find(plan => plan.value === this.radioSelected);
    }

    getSelectedTv(){
      this.tvSel = this.plan$.find(plan => plan.value === this.tvSelected);
    }

    getSelectedTvOption(){
      this.optionSel = this.plan$.find(plan => plan.value === this.tvOptionSelected);
    }

    getSelectedIp(){
      this.ipSel = this.plan$.find(plan => plan.value === this.ipSelected);
    }

    onItemChange(){
      this.getSelecteditem();
      console.log("radioSelected = ", this.radioSelected);
    }

    onTvChange(){
      this.getSelectedTv();
      console.log("tvSelected = ", this.tvSelected);
    }

    onOptionChange(){
      this.getSelectedTvOption();
      console.log("tvOptionSelected = ", this.tvOptionSelected);
    }

    onIpChange(){
      this.getSelectedIp();
      console.log("ipSelected = ", this.ipSelected);
    }

    public calcTotalPrice(){
    let sum = 0;
    sum += (+this.radioSelected) + (+this.tvSelected) + (+this.tvOptionSelected) + (+this.ipSelected);
      return sum;
      
     }

    ngOnInit() : void {
```

this.planService.getPlan(parseInt(('id'))).subscribe(res=>this.plan$=res);
}

```
}
```

And this is JSON I use to fetch data to this component:

"plan":[
{
"id": 1,
"name": "All in One",
"linespeed": [
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Basic Plan",
"speed": "50/50 Mbit/s",
"price": 149,
"quantity": 1
},
{
"name": "Essential Plan",
"speed": "100/100 Mbit/s",
"price": 199,
"quantity": 1
},
{
"id": 2,
"name": "Smart Plan",
"speed": "300/300 Mbit/s",
"price": 219,
"quantity": 1
},
{
"id": 3,
"name": "Deluxe Plan",
"speed": "500/500 Mbit/s",
"price": 249,
"quantity": 1
}

```
  ], 
  "tvpackage": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Big TV Package",
      "price": 149, 
      "quantity": 1
    }, 
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Small TV Package",
      "price": 199, 
      "quantity": 1
    }
  ],
  "tvoption": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Sport TV Package",
      "price": 149, 
      "quantity": 1
    }, 
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Movie TV Package",
      "price": 199, 
      "quantity": 1
    }
  ], 
  "iptelephony": [
    
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "No Flatrate",
      "price": 149, 
      "quantity": 1
    }, 
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Fixed Net Flatrate",
      "price": 199, 
      "quantity": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Fixed Net and Mobile Flatrate",
      "price": 249, 
      "quantity": 1
    }

  ]
```

Comment: Could you please create a small Stackblitz app and add your code there so we can help you better?